# Try to use onClick in RecyclerView and it doesn't work

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onclick, listener

I try to color buttons on recycler view, on which I click.

```
public class OneActiveButtonAdapter 
        extends RecyclerView.Adapter<OneActiveButtonAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder 
            implements View.OnClickListener {

        private Button button;
        private WeakReference<ClickListener> listenerWR;


        ViewHolder(View view, ClickListener listener) {
            super(view);
            button = view.findViewById(R.id.button);
            button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            listenerWR = new WeakReference<>(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("PRESSED", "BUTTON IS PRESSED");
        }
    }

    public interface ClickListener {
        void onPositionClicked(int position);
    }

    private ClickListener clickListener;
    private List<Payable> buttons;
    private int indexOfActivatedButton = -1;

    public OneActiveButtonAdapter(List<Payable> buttons, ClickListener clickListener) {
        this.buttons = buttons;
        this.clickListener = clickListener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return buttons.size();
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int ind) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.buttons_linear_layout,
                parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view, clickListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int ind) {
        viewHolder.button.setText(buttons.get(ind).getTitle());
        if (indexOfActivatedButton == ind) {
            viewHolder.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
        } else {
            viewHolder.button.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
}
```

'''

And code, when I create Adapter for '''RecyclerView''':

'''

```
OneActiveButtonAdapter foodRVAdapter = new OneActiveButtonAdapter(food,
        new OneActiveButtonAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositionClicked(int position) {
                Log.d("POSITION", String.valueOf(position));
            }
        });
```

'''

When I try to click on some button on the RecyclerView I expect to see Log, but it doesn't output. I also try setOnClickListener for button, but it doesn't change something.
What kind of trouble it can be?

Comment: it looks like you havent called your listener in `onClick()`

Comment: @user3170251, how can this affect the fact that the log is not output? I think, it is not necessary.

Comment: to clarify, you're not seeing `Log.d("PRESSED", "BUTTON IS PRESSED");` in your logcat?

Comment: @user3170251, yes.

Comment: try calling `view.setOnClickListener(this)` in your `ViewHolder` constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you dont setListener to your button.

remove the `listenerWR = new WeakReference<>(listener);`

and try this `button.setOnClickListener(this);`

Hope this helps.